# Selecting records in Cassandra based on Time range in frequent intervals

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

I have a table in Cassandra where i am storing events as they are coming in , different processing are done on the events at different stages. The events are entered into the table with the event occurrence time. I need to get all the events whose event time is less than a certain time and do some processing on them. As its a select range query and its invariably will use scatter gather. Can some one suggest best way to do this. This process is going to happen in every 5 secs and scatter gather happening in Cassandra happening frequently is not a good idea as its an overhead on Cassandra itself which will degrade my overall application Performance.

The table is as below:
PAS_REQ_STAGE (PartitionKey = EndpointID, category ; clusterkey= Automation_flag,alertID)

- AlertID
- BatchPickTime: Timestamp
- Automation_Threshold
- ResourceID
- ConditionID
- category
- Automation_time: Timestamp
- Automation_flag
- FilterValue

Eventtime which i have referred above is the BatchPickTime..

A scheduler wakes up at regular interval and gets all the records whose BatchPickTime is Less than the current scheduler wakeup time and sweeps them off from the table to process them.

Because of this usecase i cannot provide any specific Partition key for the query as it will have to get all data which has expired and is less than the current scheduler wake-up time.

Comment: what is your current table structure ? are u not able to specify partition key while quering ?

Comment: No cannot provide partition key during query

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow.

Please post your schema and maybe some example code with your question - you can edit it :)

The Cassandra-way of doing this is to denormalize data if necessary and build your schema around your queries. In your case I would suggest putting your events in to a table together with a time bucket:

```
CREATE TABLE events (event_source int, bucket timestamp, 
    event_time timestamp, event_text text PRIMARY KEY ((event_source, bucket),event_time));
```

The reason for this is that it is very efficent in cassandra to select a row by its so called partition key (in this example `(event_source, bucket)`) as such a query hits only one node. The reminder of the primary key is called clustering columns and defines the order of data, here all events for a day inside the bucket are sorted by `event_time`.

Try to model your event table in a way that you do not need to make multiple queries. There is a good and free data modeling course from DataStax available: https://academy.datastax.com/resources/ds220-data-modeling

One note - be careful when using cassandra as queue - this is maybe an antipattern and you might be better of with a message queue as ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ or similar.

Comment: The problem is that there is no way i can define any time bucket as a part of my Partition key because i need to select all records which are kind of expired when a scheduler wakes up and tries to sweep the table, it needs to get all records whose BatchPickTime(timestolive) in the table has expired and is less than the currenttime when scheduler is trying to sweep the table.